# Is it possible to define again rule all in snakemake?

Tags: workflow, bioinformatics, snakemake

I run in parallel processing of 8 files (fastq) with snakemake. Then each of these file is demultiplexed and I run in parallel processing of demultiplexed files generated by each of these files with snakemake again.

My first attempt (which is working well) was to use 2 snakefiles.

- a snakefile for processing 8 files in parallel
- a snakefile for processing generated demultiplexed files in parallel

I would like to use only one snakefile.

Here the solution with 2 snakefiles:

snakefile #1 for processing 8 files (wildcard `{run}`) in parallel

```py
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{folder}{run}_R1.fastq.gz", run=config["fastqFiles"],folder=config["fastqFolderPath"]),
        expand('assembled/{run}/{run}.fastq', run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('assembled/{run}/{run}.ali.fastq', run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('assembled/{run}/{run}.ali.assigned.fastq', run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('assembled/{run}/{run}.unidentified.fastq', run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('log/remove_unaligned/{run}.log',run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('log/illuminapairedend/{run}.log',run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('log/assign_sequences/{run}.log',run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('log/split_sequences/{run}.log',run=config["fastqFiles"])

include: "00-rules/assembly.smk"
include: "00-rules/demultiplex.smk"
```

snakefile #2  for processing generated demultiplexed files in parallel

```py
SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards('samples/{sample}.fasta')

rule all:
    input:
        expand('samples/{sample}.uniq.fasta',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('samples/{sample}.l.u.fasta',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('samples/{sample}.r.l.u.fasta',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('samples/{sample}.c.r.l.u.fasta',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('log/dereplicate_samples/{sample}.log',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('log/goodlength_samples/{sample}.log',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('log/clean_pcrerr/{sample}.log',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('log/rm_internal_samples/{sample}.log',sample=SAMPLES)

include: "00-rules/filtering.smk"
```

This solution is working well.

Is it possible to merge these 2 snakefiles into one this way ?

```py
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{folder}{run}_R1.fastq.gz", run=config["fastqFiles"],folder=config["fastqFolderPath"]),
        expand('assembled/{run}/{run}.fastq', run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('assembled/{run}/{run}.ali.fastq', run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('assembled/{run}/{run}.ali.assigned.fastq', run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('assembled/{run}/{run}.unidentified.fastq', run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('log/remove_unaligned/{run}.log',run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('log/illuminapairedend/{run}.log',run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('log/assign_sequences/{run}.log',run=config["fastqFiles"]),
        expand('log/split_sequences/{run}.log',run=config["fastqFiles"])

include: "00-rules/assembly.smk"
include: "00-rules/demultiplex.smk"

SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards('samples/{sample}.fasta')

rule all:
    input:
        expand('samples/{sample}.uniq.fasta',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('samples/{sample}.l.u.fasta',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('samples/{sample}.r.l.u.fasta',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('samples/{sample}.c.r.l.u.fasta',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('log/dereplicate_samples/{sample}.log',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('log/goodlength_samples/{sample}.log',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('log/clean_pcrerr/{sample}.log',sample=SAMPLES),
        expand('log/rm_internal_samples/{sample}.log',sample=SAMPLES)

include: "00-rules/filtering.smk"
```

So i have to define again `rule all`.

and i got the following message error:

```
The name all is already used by another rule
```

Is they're a way to have many `rule all` or the solution "using many snakefiles" is the only one possible ?

I would like to use snakemake in the most appropriate way possible.

Comment: I am probably not understanding the question correctly, but why not put all the input of one of the two rule alls in the rule of the other?

Comment: Also an option is to give them different names (e.g. all_2), and run `snakemake all_2`

Comment: Have you looked into [`sub-workflows` option](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#sub-workflows) to have dependent workflows?

Comment: Even if you combine the two all rules into one, you will have a problem where the glob_wildcards function is executed at the initialization of the workflow, but I don't think those files are created until the demultiplexing is done. You can use subworkflows as Manavalan suggested, or use checkpoints: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande because input files of "step 2" needed the glob_wildcard function (they're very numerous and created by "step1") and are not dependent of the wildcard `{run}` of input files of "step1" but of course if they're a way to do the declaration of all the input files into one `rule all` i will be delighted

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy the sub-workflows option is very interesting, thanks a lot. I will explore this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are not limited in the naming of the top level rule. You may call it `all`, or you may rename it: the only thing that matters is the order of their definition. By default Snakemake takes the first rule as the target one and then constructs the graph of dependencies.

Taking that in consideration you have several options. First, you can merge both top-level rules from the workflows into one. At the end of the day your `all` rules do nothing except of the definition of the target files. Next, you may rename your rules into `all1` and `all2` (making it possible to run a single workflow if you specify that in command line), and provide the `all` rule with merged input. Finally you can use subworkflows, but as long as your intention is to squash two scripts into one, that would be an overkill.

One more hint that could help: you don't need to specify the pattern `expand('filename{sample}',sample=config["fastqFiles"])` for each file if you define a distinct output for each run. For example:

```
rule sample:
    input:
        'samples/{sample}.uniq.fasta',
        'samples/{sample}.l.u.fasta',
        'samples/{sample}.r.l.u.fasta',
        'samples/{sample}.c.r.l.u.fasta',
        'log/dereplicate_samples/{sample}.log',
        'log/goodlength_samples/{sample}.log',
        'log/clean_pcrerr/{sample}.log',
        'log/rm_internal_samples/{sample}.log'
    output:
        temp('flag_sample_{sample}_complete')
```

In this case the `all` rule becomes trivial:

```
rule all:
    input: expand('flag_sample_{sample}_complete', sample=SAMPLES)
```

Or, as I advised before:

```
rule all:
    input: expand('flag_run_{run}_complete', run=config["fastqFiles"]),
    input: expand('flag_sample_{sample}_complete', sample=SAMPLES)

rule all1:
    input: expand('flag_run_{run}_complete', run=config["fastqFiles"])

rule all2:
    input: expand('flag_sample_{sample}_complete', sample=SAMPLES)
```